# Merge 2 dataframes, ignore rows from right DataFrame that don't appear in left DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

df1:

```
number | pid
1      | a
1      | aaa
2      | b
3      | c
3      | chh
```

df2:

```
number | pod
1      | axa
2      | bvb
3      | ckc
4      | dld
```

I would like to add column df["pod"] to df1, mapped by column "number". Ignoring all df2["number"] that don't appear in df1["number"].

End result should be:

```
number | pid | pod
1      | a   | axa
1      | aaa | axa
2      | b   | bvb
3      | c   | ckc
3      | chh | ckc
```

I thought a "left" join would do this but it blows up my df.shape from 542 to 304534 rows? A lot of rows are duplicated after the merge, removing those shrinks my df1 to 251 rows instead of giving me the original 542 rows with just one extra column?

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["number"], how="left")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are duplicated in `df2['number']` column, possible solution is remove duplicated in `df2` by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df1, df2.drop_duplicates('number'), on=["number"], how="left")
```